# after upgrading the Spring boot version to 2.6, getting circular dependency error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, circular-dependency

Spring boot application failed to start after upgrading to 2.6.4 due to circular dependency.

I have two class like this:

```
class ABC{

    @Autowired
    PQR pqr;
}

Class PQR{

    @Autowired
    ABC abc;
}
```

previously working fine, now getting circular dependency error after upgrading spring boot to 2.6.4

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write @Lazy annotation at top of one of the autowire . This will let your spring application compile without any error

Like below:

```
Class PQR{
@Lazy
@Autowired
ABC abc;
}
```

Comment: its not work in my case, could you please help me how i use setter or postConstruct to avoid circular dependency

Comment: Are you using @Lazy in only one of the injection.Also,try recompiling the app and show the error which you are getting after this

Comment: @Lazy annotation working now. Thanks!!